# Duda con Pruebas unitarias Junit

Tags: java

Estoy realizando unas pruebas unitarias con Junit y tengo una duda para hacer un ejercicio.

Al crearse la clase test, se crean casos de prueba para cada método. Ahora bien, si quieres probar únicamente un método... ¿es conveniente eliminar el resto de tests que se han creado para cada método?, ¿o se deben quedar tal y como están todos?

Además, si tengo una clase instanciada en la clase principal con sus atributos inicializados con valores exactos (por ejemplo: cantidad de dinero en una cuenta entre otros), a la hora de realizar el test de un metodo "retirarDinero", ¿la clase Test se supone que debe contar con ese atributo inicializado en la clase principal para recalcular el saldo no? ¿o debo iniciar una variable en el test del método para que el test se pueda ejecutar?

Hola, tengo otra duda, sigo con las pruebas unitarias y no entiendo que tengo mal en el siguiente código:

```
@Test
public double testIngresar() throws Exception {       
    System.out.println("ingresar");
    CCuenta instance = new CCuenta();
    double resultado = instance.ingresar(100.5);
    assertEquals(2600.5, resultado);
    System.out.print(resultado);
}
```

El error que me sale de "tipos incompatibles, void no puede ser convertido a double" en la linea en la que declaro la variable resultado no entiendo porque me sale. El método ingresar() está declarado en la clase CClase como double también, tengo un pequeño lío de conceptos como podéis ver...

Comment: Puedes ejecutar todos los test cases o puedes indicar qué test case(s) ejecutar. Esto depende de cómo ejecutes los tests.

Comment: No entiendes el error que te sale? si me dices que no te lo puedo explicar en un comentario creo que es simple.

Comment: Deberías haber añadido la clase CCuenta a la pregunta, tiene pinta de que te estás liando entre el tipo de párametro que recibe y el tipo que devuelve

Comment: Cuando creo una clase de pruebas para una clase existente, con x número de métodos, voy implementando y ejecutando los test poco a poco. Para empezar comento las anotaciones `@Test` y descomento sólo las de las pruebas que quiero lanzar. Creo que esto se ajustaría a lo que necesitas.

Comment: Actualmente esta pregunta incluye múltiples preguntas en una. Debería centrarse en un solo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres trabajar con pruebas unitarias se recomienda implementar pruebas para todos los métodos. Si el método es trivial, también el test lo es, así no pierdas mucho tiempo. Si en algun momento hay que mantener un método que fue trivial para empezar y te sale un error, vas a estar agradecido por las pruebas implementados.

Cuando creas pruebas con datos variables, acceso a BD o otras actividades más complejos vas a tener que armar un contexto para las puebas, en algunos casos te conviene crear un "mock" del componente real que usa el mismo interfaz.

El tema es bien amplio, así si tienes casos concretos es más facil de proveer código de ejemplo.